# Remote-Containers: Can I create a standard default devcontainer.json?

Tags: vscode-remote

So I have one local container that I want to use for the Remote-Containers support.  But I can't seem to create a single default devcontainer.json to utilize this.  Am I correct that it's a file per project or repository?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Connect to a container created outside of VS Code?

Comment: Correct - trying to clone a github repo that doesn't have a devcontainer.json file.  I've got a custom image that I built to cover several different SDKs, but I can't figure out how to create a devcontainer.json to use for the repo.  And creating a folder structure for every different GitHub repo I might go to is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to have the `devcontainer.json` version-controlled in the repository, so that anyone checking the repo out can use the standard container configuration.

If you're cloning a 3rd party repo which you want to run locally in a container, you will need to create the config file yourself if it's missing.

If you find yourself in need of the same devcontainer config over and over again, consider submitting a pull request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers.

Having said that, it should be straightforward to create the config. If you're going to use an existing Docker image it is as simple as creating a single file:

`.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`

```json
{
    "image": "local image name or remote url"
}
```

If you have a Dockerfile you want to build from, again it's a single option:

```json
{
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile"
}
```

That's all you need. Fire `Reopen in container` VS Code command and you're set.

If you want to configure port mapping, or change the user you will need to add that of course, but anyway it will be quite minimal.

Comment: The issue is that if you create the devcontainer locally - Remote-Tools is not aware of it and there is no way to use it without pushing it to the github repository that you mentioned. That is ithe problem.
Simple scenario - you want to open a GH repo that "doesn't" have a devcontainer.json file in a container.  You don't want to PR a devcontainer.json file to the repo you mentioned, and you don't want to create the folder structure as demonstrated in the documentation for every repo you visit.
How do you create the devcontainer.json file then?

Comment: It doesn't have to be added to git, but it has to be in the project folder at a known location: either `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` or `.devcontainer.json`.

Comment: got it - that's what i thought.  created a feature request to add this.  thanks

Comment: If it's a github issue, please post a link here too for someone coming here in the future. Cheers.

Comment: [Use locally defined devcontainer.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4561)